# Time format to be changed to 30 minute interval in Power BI

Tags: if-statement, powerbi

I need to change the time format to 30 minute format . Below is the example :

`3:27:16 am` needs to be changed to `3:00 am` interval.

I need 'if' statement to used in Power BI.

Comment: In DAX or in PowerQuery?

Comment: what if the value is - 3:37:16 am

Comment: Hi Murray, I need the if statement in PowerQuery...please help.

Answer (score 1):

In DAX:

MyTime = TIME(HOUR('Table'[TimeValue]), IF (MINUTE('Table'[TimeValue]) < 30, 0, 30), 0)